# add constraint ,modify and constriants

Tags: mysql, sql

Do `PRIMARY KEY,FOREIGN KEY, NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY` and `CHECK` constraints are categorized.

I want to know when `add` constraint and `modify` are used.

```
ALTER TABLE dept MODIFY deptId int(3) PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE dept ADD CONSTRAINT deptId int(3) PRIMARY KEY;
```

which I have to use for different constraints.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Is it about the difference between those two `alter table` statements? You use `MODIFY` when you want to modify an existing constraint. `ADD` is for adding a new constrain which didn't exist before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are exactly trying to know but you use `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD` for adding new items (columns,constraints) to table schema/structure.

```
ALTER TABLE dept ADD CONSTRAINT deptId int(3) PRIMARY KEY;
```

You use `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY` to modify/change structure. That is to change a column data type, size, adding constraint to that column

```
ALTER TABLE dept MODIFY deptId int(3) PRIMARY KEY;
```

So, instead of making a PK, you can also make that column non-nullable (add NOT NULL constraint to that column) like below

```
ALTER TABLE dept MODIFY deptId int(3) NOT NULL;
```

Even change it's size like

```
ALTER TABLE dept MODIFY deptId int(6);
```

Comment: @SaiPhani, don't forget to mark it as answer. It will be closed then.